# Unable to access object values with mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm facing weird problem, when accessing values of object.

I'm using `mongoose` for querying MongoDB, (`findOne` operation in this specific).

Returned value is saved into `product` variable.

This code snippet

```
console.log(product);
console.log(product.auth);
```

output this

```
{ _id: '56bde5cab581548421b5c1bf',
  product_identifier: 'oo',
  auth: { public: 'publickey', private: 'private_key' },
  created_at: 1455285691,
  deleted_at: null,
  flags: [],
  final_states: [ 3, 4 ] }
undefined
```

So my problem is that I'm not able to access inside values of an object. Just to make sure that it's not because of async behaviour of NodeJS, I reversed the order of both `console.log` statements, and it is still `undefined` After quick googling I find out that `console.log` is not reliable. So I did `console.log(JSON.stringify(product));` which outputs

```
{"_id":"56bde5cab581548421b5c1bf","product_identifier":"oo","auth":{"public":"publickey","private":"private_key"},"created_at":1455285691,"deleted_at":null,"flags":[],"final_states":[3,4]}
```

(As expected)
So for sure value is there. 
So I tried this

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product)).auth);
```

And boom!, it worked.
(output - `{ public: 'publickey', private: 'private_key' }`)

I'm absolutely sure that it is not Object inside Array issue, which was most questions on the internet, I could find. What am I missing here?

PS - TBH, I'm really counting on `mongoose` bug

Edit - 
`console.log(typeof product)` outputs `object`, if that helps

Edit 2 -
`console.log(product.final_states)` is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of document stored in MongoDB is BSON, we can try to convert the `product` to Object through [`toObject`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toObject) or [`toJSON`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON)

```
console.log(product.toJSON().auth);
```